# Biblatex: sorting by title if no author

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

I would like to sort my bibliography by title in the case there is no author but just the editor. Now it is sorting by editor.

So in my example I would like to have first "Concilium Foroiuliense" and then Hergenröther.

There are lots of threads about sorting but I couldn't find one with this (or a close related) issue. Should I redefine the alphabetic template (biblatex manual p.257), use a sortkey or... what?

MWE:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX TS-program = xelatexmk

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}


@book{Her:Mon,
    Address = {Ratisbonae},
    Editor = {Joseph Hergenröther},
    Langid = {german},
    Publisher = {Manz},
    Title = {Monumenta graeca ad Photium},
    Year = {1869}}


@incollection{Mgh:Aqu,
    Address = {Hannoverae-Lipsiae},
    Booktitle = {Monumenta Germaniae Historiae. Legum \textsc{iii}. Concilia aevi Karolini \textsc{ii}/1},
    Editor = {Albertus Werminghoff},
    Langid = {german},
    Pages = {177-95},
    Publisher = {Impensis Bibliopolii Hahniani},
    Title = {Concilium Foroiuliense},
    Year = {1906}}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french, german}

\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,
            language=auto,
            ibidpage=true,
            autolang=other,% use new option name
            useprefix=true,
            giveninits=true,
            indexing=true,% or cite?
            citepages=separate,%
            dateabbrev=false,
            backend=biber,
        ]{biblatex}



\addbibresource{archivio.bib}  

\begin{document}
First, I'm citing this\footcite{Mgh:Aqu}\\
Then this\footcite{Her:Mon}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`useeditor` is the option you are looking for. If `useeditor` is set to `false` the editor will appear after the title and the work will be sorted by title.

You can add the option globally for all `@incollection` entries with

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[incollection]{useeditor=false}
```

or locally for only specific books by using the `options` field in the `.bib` file

```
@incollection{Mgh:Aqu,
  address   = {Hannoverae-Lipsiae},
  booktitle = {Monumenta Germaniae Historiae. Legum \textsc{iii}. Concilia aevi Karolini \textsc{ii}/1},
  editor    = {Albertus Werminghoff},
  langid    = {german},
  pages     = {177-95},
  publisher = {Impensis Bibliopolii Hahniani},
  title     = {Concilium Foroiuliense},
  year      = {1906},
  options   = {useeditor=false},
}
```

I would not set `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{useeditor=false}` for all entries since `@collection`s and `Her:Mon` in your example should probably still be associated with their editors.